# Why isn't my child theme using the new style.css file?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I followed a very simple tutorial on how to enqueue a child theme, but when I actually went to edit my style.css nothing transferred over. Did I use the *given* code wrong?

**style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: Blank Slate Child
Theme URI: http://www.efficientmind.org/blankslate-child/

*/
```

**Enqueue code in the functions.php**

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand...Are you saying nothing happens when you edit the child theme *style.css*?

Comment: @rnevius Exactly. I added code to attempt to modify one of my elements and nothing happened.

Comment: I'm reading through [another tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402) now and it says that I need to "register" my child themes style.css...but the other one made no mention of this! How important is this?

Answer (score 2):

Your child theme stylesheet header needs to contain the Template line (the parent theme name) in order to work.

[codex | child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Example:

```
/*
Theme Name:     Twenty Thirteen Child
Theme URI:      http://example.com/
Description:    Child theme for the Twenty Thirteen theme
Author:         Your name here
Author URI:     http://example.com/about/
Template:       twentythirteen
Version:        0.1.0
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

add following comment to your child theme's style.css file:

```
Template: BlankSlate
```

your new Style.css should then look like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: Blank Slate Child
Theme URI: http://www.efficientmind.org/blankslate-child/
Template: BlankSlate
*/
```